AWS Cognito User Pools Across Environments
I am implementing AWS Cognito user pools with client credentials for my machine-to-machine OAuth flow. Part of this process is setting up a custom domain name - such as auth.example.com.
The team is having a discussion around going with separate auth endpoints per environment (eg. auth-dev., auth-uat., auth.) and the separation this provides between Cognito user pool (and associated) resources.
Option 1 is having completely separate Cognito user pools, scopes, and custom domain name per environment, while Option 2 is using a shared Cognito user pools for all client credentials, scopes and other resources.
Is having an auth-dev/auth-uat.example.com an anti-pattern for OAuth endpoints? And is going with a single user pool a worthwhile risk to retain the same domain name for your OAuth endpoint?
Do you have any experience implementing Cognito following option 1, or option 2? Is there an alternative implementation I'm missing?
